# Data truncation for enum in Java and MySQL (java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for ...)

Tags: java, database, parsing, enums, truncate

I have a custom class that represents a .csv file structure, which later read in into an arrayList of this class. It has the following tags:

```
public class InputFile {

public enum Status {
    IN_STOCK,
    OUT_OF_STOCK
}

private int lineNumber;
private String sku;
private Status statusCode;
private Date orderDate;

public InputFile(int lineNumber, String sku, Status status, Date orderDate) {
    this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    this.sku = sku;
    statusCode = status;
    setOrderDate(orderDate);
}

public Status getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Status input) {
    statusCode = input;
}
```

Here is the simplified .csv file:

```
LineNumber;SKU;Status;OrderDate
1;553555254;IN_STOCK;2018-04-21
2;668470653;IN_STOCK;2018-05-08
3;899395925;OUT_OF_STOCK;2018-06-06
```

When I read these into the arrayList and put the individual statuses on consolse just to check, it shows correctly (IN_STOCK, OUT_OF_STOCK). However, when I try to insert it into the database it gets truncated:

> java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'Status' at row 1

Here is the code for database upload:

```
try {
     String orderItemQuery = "INSERT INTO `order_processing`.`order_item` (`OrderItemId`, `OrderId`, `SalePrice`, `ShippingPrice`, `Sku`, `Status`)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

     PreparedStatement orderItemStmt = conn.prepareStatement(orderItemQuery);
     for (InputFile i : CSVManager.getList())
     {
         orderItemStmt.setInt (1, i.getOrderItemId());
         orderItemStmt.setInt(2,i.getOrderId());
         orderItemStmt.setDouble (3, i.getSalePrice());
         orderItemStmt.setDouble (4, i.getShippingPrice());
         orderItemStmt.setString (5, i.getSku());
         orderItemStmt.setObject(6, InputFile.Status.valueOf(i.getStatusCode().toString()));
         orderItemStmt.execute();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

And here is the .sql for the database table:

```
create table order_item
(
  OrderItemId    int         not null
    primary key,
  OrderId        int         not null,
  SalePrice      decimal     not null,
  ShippingPrice  decimal     not null,
  TotalItemPrice decimal AS (ShippingPrice + SalePrice) not null,
  SKU            varchar(25) not null,
  Status         enum ('OUT_OF_STOCK', 'IN_STOCK') not null,
  constraint order_item_order_OrderId_fk
    foreign key (OrderId) references `order` (OrderId)
);
```

What is missing? Why the enum gets truncated?

> EDIT: The problem was that Java enum types have a different ordinal numbers then MYSQL has. Java starts counting from 0 while MYSQL starts from 1. To solve the difference, a modification needed in the ordinal list in my enums:

```
    public enum Status {
    OUT_OF_STOCK (1),
    IN_STOCK (2);

    private int status;

    private Status (final int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Then inserting data into the database was sample:

```
orderItemStmt.setInt(6, i.getStatusCode().getStatus());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the enum type on SQL is stored as a number. It's size is 1 or 2 bytes. If you want to store the textual version of status field, then declare the column as varchar. Or you should store the ordinal of status.

Comment: Storing as a varchar would solve my problem, but the exercise insists on storing in the database as an Enum type as well.

Comment: Then use .ordinal() method on enumeration to get integer representstion

Answer (score 0):

Use Status.valueOf("IN_STOCK") and IN_STOCK.name() when you save your data to database.

Comment: I don't know the value of Status (it could be 'IN_STOCK' and 'OUT_OF_STOCK', but not known until the CSV file read and not important to know the exact value). That's why I used a for loop for the arrayList to put it into the database. The parsing seems OK but it still fails to insert and the data gets truncated every time.